# Remove commit in remote

Tags: git

I've done commit and push to the remote branch without realizing it, and now I want to undo that commit remotely without losing the changes. I'm looking for StackOverflow and Google but the information I find is different according to who writes.

I want to revert the last commit in remote and keep maintaining the changes in local without tracking to be able to take those changes to another branch locally.

Right now, as I read, I would have to do:

```
git revert HEAD
git stash -m "message"
git checkout branch
git stash apply
git add.
git commit -m "message"
git push
```

I've also read that I could cherry-pick to take a commit to another branch, which would make something like this:

```
git revert HEAD
git checkout branch
git cherry-pick id_commit
git push
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're right, a cherry-pick would be good here, but I'll suggest what I think is an easier way:

Simply run `git rebase --onto other-branch master~1 master` (This says "rebase the range of commits between last-before master and master (your latest commit) and re-play it onto other-branch"

Or, if you'd prefer cherry-picking, I believe the process is as follows:

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git rev-parse HEAD` from master to see the last commit hash, we'll pretend it was `1234567`...
3. `git checkout other-branch`
4. `git cherry-pick -x 1234567` to apply commit `1234567` to the current branch.

---

After you've either rebased or cherry-picked from the above instructions, you can optionally erase the commit from master:

1. `git checkout master`
2. `git reset HEAD --hard` (remove last commit on master)
3. `git push --force` (forcefully update remote synced branch with new history for this branch

Then, work on your code on `other-branch` and merge into master and push whenever you're finished with local work

Comment: But in this case I would not lose my changes? what I want to do is apply the changes I made to master in the branch that is already created and that in the example would be a branch

Comment: No, master would not have them, but your new branch would. But I'm not 100% sure I follow then. Do you want to make a new branch off of the commit, or move your existing commit on top of an already existing branch?

Comment: Looking for more information on my own I have seen that maybe I could merge the changes against my branch, then push and gout checkout to master to then revert HEAD and then push -f origin master, how do you see it?

Comment: That could work, if the only difference between master and your other branch is the one new commit on master and new commits on other branch. So if you had 2 new commits on master but only wanted the latest, that wouldn't work. So my answer is the more general solution, where in your case you may be able to get away with a merge if you just have one commit on master you want to move.

Comment: You understand rebase but not cherry picking?

Comment: It's been a hot few years since I've looked at cherry picking, learned rebase during that time. Upon second glance today, super simple and a great fit for this case indeed. I'll amend my answer with an option for cherry picking